# interaction does not exist in the current context c# textbox

Tags: c#

at the beginning i have included the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` Namespace

```
private void btnAddHousehold_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Address = Interaction.InputBox("Enter the Address of the new Household","Add new Household");
    if (Address != "")
    {
        Household temp = new Household();
        temp.Address = Address;
        Program.Households.Add(temp);
        SaveToFile();
        RefreshForm();
    }
}
```

I expect a textbox to popout and ask for the Address of Household

Comment: Please post the complete code. We need to see the imports. Also consider using code snippets

Comment: Note that just using the namespace in your source code files is not sufficient. You also need to add the respective assembly which provides the implementation for the Interaction class/module (`Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll`; as told by the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction?view=netframework-4.7.2) as a reference to your project...